# Can't get Keycloak to add new users/groups to OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap, keycloak, federated

I've been banging my head against the wall for two days on this one now.

I have setup fresh Keycloak and OpenLDAP instances, and I want to use OpenLDAP as the source of truth for all user data. I want to use Keycloak to create and edit users. Then, the new/modified users should be synced to OpenLDAP.

I tested this setup a while back with Keycloak v13 and it worked perfectly. Now I'm trying to put it into production with Keycloak v19 and I can't make Keycloak actually write *anything* to OpenLDAP. I don't even see LDAP write attempts in the Keycloak logs (cranked up to TRACE) when I create new users/groups in Keycloak.

I know the LDAP connection works because if I manually create a new group in OpenLDAP it will show up in Keycloak, but I can't get sync to work the other way.

#### My LDAP Setup

```
# Base organization
dn: dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: dcObject
objectClass: organization
dc: example
o: Example Company

# Organizational Unit for our Users
dn: ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Users

# Organizational Unit for our Groups
dn: ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: organizationalUnit
ou: Groups
```

#### My User Federation Setup

[image: Keycloak user federation settings]

#### My Group Sync Setup

[image: Keycloak LDAP group mapper settings]

#### Ideas

- The Sync registrations [is missing](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/13829) in v19. So, maybe that's why it's not trying to write to the LDAP server. But, that shouldn't affect groups and I'm not seeing new groups created either.
- ...I'm at a loss

Any ideas why Keycloak doesn't want to write any changes to OpenLDAP?